# Python H5PY IOError: Unable to open file..... error message = 'no such file or directory'

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, h5py, cudamat

```
data_loc = os.path.join('data', 'datasets', data_code + '.hdf5')
data = h5py.File(data_loc, 'r')
```

By the way I am using Window 10 x64

I am getting error while I run
`python train.py fcn_rffc4 brats_fold0 brats_fold0 600 -ch False` command

Error is shortly, IOError Unable to open file.... beacuse 'no such file or directory'
Long error that I got is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "train.py", line 305, in 
start_training(model_code, data_code, checkpoint, max_passes=n_epochs, train_dir=train_dir)

File "train.py", line 273, in start_training
coach, model_def = setup_training(model_code, data_code, checkpoint, max_passes)

File "train.py", line 140, in setup_training
train, valid, test = retrieve_data(data_code=data_code)

File "train.py", line 57, in retrieve_data
data = h5py.File(data_loc, 'r')

File "C:\Users\yunus\Anaconda3\envs\medical_image\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\files.py", line 271, in init
fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)

File "C:\Users\yunus\Anaconda3\envs\medical_image\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\files.py", line 101, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
File "h5py_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open

IOError: Unable to open file (Unable to open file: name = 
'data\datasets\brats_fold0.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'no such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

Comment: Either provide the full path to `h5py.File()` , or change your directory using `os.chdir(path)`

Comment: Are you totally sure the file you're referring to is in the working directory + data\datasets\brats_fold0.hdf5?